# Average of similar rows with different values and make them one

Tags: r, average

This is my small data frame

```
head(ATAC_fc_plot)
          ENSEMBL    Peak log2FoldChange
1 ENSG00000230368   Peak4       1.565676
2 ENSG00000230368   Peak6       2.537395
3 ENSG00000230368   Peak7      -1.543704
4 ENSG00000230368   Peak8      -3.498416
5 ENSG00000067606 Peak112       1.982703
6 ENSG00000067606 Peak113       2.035416
```

I have these rows repeated due to various levels of enrichment so i have to take a final avg of each of the row. For example I have 4 "`ENSG00000230368`" observation I would like to make it one row with the average.

Output I would like to see is this  "`ENSG00000230368`" and "`ENSG00000067606`".The middle column is the reference for me like each gene is coming from which peak. So it can also be removed if its an issue.

Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Even though you copied and pasted your data as presented in the R console, potential helpers cannot really use it as it is right now. I suggest you run `dput(head(ATAC_fc_plot))` and edit your question by adding what you get from it. This will allow us to get your data easier.

Comment: I missed that..will edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

ATAC_fc_plot %>%
  group_by(ENSEMBL) %>%
  summarize(average = mean(log2FoldChange, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: when Im doing dput(head(dataframe) the whole dataset is coming not sure what is the issue...

Comment: I ran it , this is the dataset https://ghostbin.co/paste/vhxug , the issue is Im getting only 1 average .now the Same rows being averaged out together

Comment: @PesKchan The reason for this result is that the values in the `ENSEMBL` column are all different from each other. Run the following code to see what I mean: `length(unique(ATAC_fc_plot $ENSEMBL))` and the result is `2410`. What this code does is it tells you how many unique values there are in the `ENSEMBL` column. So you can see that they are all different.

Comment: yes that i did see. 2410 is the unique my objective is as such for example this ID "ENSG00000230368 appears 4 times in the row. So I would like to see only once and the one ID would have value of all the average .The background of the data "ENSG00000230368" this gene has multiple signal so i would like to take the average of it .

Comment: I understand what you want. However, there is no case in your data where `"ENSG00000230368"` appears four times in a row. Actually, there is no gene that is repeated more than once (regardless of whether the repetitions are next to each other or not). If there was, then the code I provided would work.

Comment: Peak 4,6,7,8 they are the same "ENSG00000230368" with different accessibility values ," there is no case in your data where "ENSG00000230368" appears four times in a row." this appears 4 times isn't it?

Comment: @PesKchan You must be referring to the data in the original question. I was talking about the data that you shared with me here: https://ghostbin.co/paste/vhxug

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226740/discussion-between-peskchan-and-savedbyjesus).

Comment: yes ..this is the data which would like your help https://ghostbin.co/paste/4unby

Comment: Is there any way I can only average the positive values? for the same ENSEMBL ID ? and make a new column